# usage of the virtual folder in CQ5

Tags: aem, sling

In the Properties and Child Nodes of a Component I can see the following:

- **Name : virtual**
- Type : sling:Folder
- Description : Enables creation of virtual components. To see an
  example, please look at the contact component at
  /libs/foundation/components/profile/form/contact.

But I am curious about the usage of this `virtual`. Can any one explain about this `virtual` usage if possible with an example?

Answer (score 3):

I think good example is Column Control `/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/colctrl` component. It's creates a number of columns, each containing a paragraph system. It also have [`virtual`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/custom_node_types.html#cq%3aComponent) folder with 4 virtual components:

- 2 Columns,
- 2 Columns Recommend,
- 2 Columns Sidebar
- 3 Columns.

All these components are visible in the sidekick as separate items. They can have different icons, titles and descriptions. Each one contains different initial data (copied from `cq:formParameters` node). They have, however, the same logic and can't be recognized from the original `colctrl` after creating them.

More information on virtual component can be found in the [Adobe doc](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/custom_node_types.html#cq%3aVirtualComponent).